# How to access an internal service on a loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kind

I am deploying a k8s cluster locally using Kind.  The image gets deployed ok and when I view the list of services I see the following

[image]

the service I'm trying to access is `chatt-service` and if you notice the `EXTERNAL-IP` is pending.  I know minikube has a command which makes this accessible, but how do I do it on a `Kind` cluster ?

Answer (score 9):

for Loadbalancer service type you will not able to get public ip because you're running it locally and you will need to run it in a cloud provider which will provide the LB for you like ALB in aws or LoadBalancer in Digital ocean. however, you can access this service locally using the Kubectl proxy tool.

.

```
kubectl port-forward service/chatt-service 3002:3002
```

Comment: thanks for this, let me try it out and see.

Comment: Worked for me after struggling a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in `3002:3002`, the first port will be the target port on `localhost` to access the service. The second port is the original service port.

Answer (score 3):

There are some additional options to work on LoadBalancer under Kind cluster. (While the port forwarding is the simplest way).

https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/loadbalancer/

First way:

> You can also expose pods and services using extra port mappings
> this mean manually set ports in cluster-config.yaml

And maybe second way (but not actually the solution on LoadBalancer):

> You may want to check out the Ingress Guide as a cross-platform
> workaround